# Is the "volatile" property of pointers inherited?

Tags: c, pointers, volatile

Suppose I have the following code:

```
my_struct_member_type *foo() {
    volatile my_struct *s = (my_struct *)SOME_ADDRESS;
    return &(s->struct_member);
}
```

Is the pointer returned by foo also volatile?

EDIT: A followup: is the pointer `&(s->struct_member)` volatile inside of foo?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303660/volatile-variables-as-argument-to-function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

For `volatile my_struct *s` says that the object you see through it is `volatile` and all members that you access through this pointer inherit the `volatile` qualification.

Having the address of a pointer to `volatile` returned if the return type doesn't say so is a constraint violation and your compiler *must* have given you a diagnostic for that.

**Edit:** There also seems to be confusion to where the `volatile` keyword applies. In your example it applies to the object pointed to, not to the pointer itself. As a rule of thumb always write the qualifiers (`const` or `volatile`) as far to the right as possible without a type change. Your example then would read:

```
my_struct volatile*s = (my_struct *)SOME_ADDRESS;
```

which is entirely different from

```
my_struct *volatile s = (my_struct *)SOME_ADDRESS;
```

where the pointer itself is `volatile` but not the object behind it.

**Edit 2:** Since you ask for my *sources*, the actual C standard, C11, 6.8.6.4 it says about the `return` statement:

> If the expression has a type different from the return type of the
>   function in which it appears, the value is converted as if by
>   assignment to an object having the return type of the function

So 6.15.16.1 for the assignment operator what is expected from the conversion:

> the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type,
>   and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue
>   conversion) both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified
>   versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has
>   all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;

Here the pointed type on the right has the `volatile` qualifier in addtion to the one on the left.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if an object at some address was declared volatile via pointer declaration, then it becomes a volatile object in every possible scope of the program? Even scopes that know nothing of the pointer which gave it the volatile property? Also, considering the disagreement we see in the answers here, can you mention some sources for your information?

Comment: You have to distinguish the object itself and the type through which you access it. You only declare and define an object in one single place, it then is volatile or not. If you access a volatile object it through a pointer that says that it isn't volatile is so-called *undefined behavior*, that is anything can happen up to crashing your program or stealing your money.

Comment: Also found this link with some useful information: http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter8/const_and_volatile.html

Answer (score 1):

No. `volatile` is a compiler hint, and as such is only respected as long as the compiler can see it. That function could be called from another translation unit, which would have no idea about you declaring the pointer `volatile` initially.

Comment: A followup: is the pointer &(s->struct_member) volatile inside of foo?

Comment: I think, yes, because, `&(s->struct_member)== s+offsetof(typeof(s), struct_member)`

Comment: I'm not so sure... This is a new value. It's not the same as s, and it's not a variable; as I understand it, volatile is a property of variable, not value. I would like some confirmation on this theory though.

Comment: `volatile my_struct * a` means the content of the struct will be treated as volatile as long as you access it through the `a` pointer. But doing `int * i = &a->member`, `i` will *not* be treated as volatile.
If you want to flag the pointer itself as volatile you would do `my_struct * volatile a;` instead.

Comment: @HampusNilsson, `int * i = &a->member` is a constraint violation and thus the behavior of the program is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Volatile has no sense in runtime, it is used to tell compiler to not optimize access to a variable.

Returning volatile pointer is nonsense. You mark some storage (lvalue) as volatile, not rvalue.

http://www.barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/C-Volatile-Keyword

Comment: Sorry but your answer make absolutely no sense at all.

Comment: But he is not returning a `volatile` pointer, but a pointer to a `volatile` object, and that makes perfect sense.

Comment: Question was: "Is the pointer returned by foo also volatile?"

Comment: No, the pointer isn't declared `volatile`. To have that also the declaration would have to read `my_struct volatile*volatile s`. Pointers are only affected if the qualifier is to the right of the `*`.