# Casting volatile variable in c

Tags: c, casting, volatile

I think I have a tricky question, but I'm sure you will be able to help me.
Let's say I have a function like this:

```
char my_function (int example);
```

I use this function in multiple cases, sometimes the argument it receives is a volatile variable and sometimes a non-volatile variable.
That cause some warnings when I compile my code that can be easily removed by using casts, but I want to understand which is the safer scenario and why.

Scenario 1:

Prototype: `char my_function (int example);`

```
int a;
volatile int b;

my_function (a);  // Everything is fine.
my_function ((int)b);  // Avoided the warning, by casting the variable and            saying it's no longer volatile.
```

Scenario 2:

Prototype: `char my_function (volatile int example);`

```
int a;
volatile int b;

my_function(b);  // Everything is fine.
my_function((volatile int)a); // Avoided the warning, by casting 'a' saying that now it's volatile.
```

I understand how volatile modifier works, I mostly use it because I program micro-controllers and I need to ensure that some of my variables are never optimized out when they are hardware modified. 
I am a bit confused about casting the volatile modifier and that is why I want to understand which is the safer scenario apart from just removing the warning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [volatile variables as argument to function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303660/volatile-variables-as-argument-to-function)

Comment: To fix the root cause declare `my_function` with a `volatile` parameter

Comment: `volatile` is not a modifier, but a qualifier. There are no modifiers in C. And your question is not clear. Although you state different, your text lets suspect you do not know how `volatile` works. Revisit your C book or get a better one. And never cast an expression until you are aware of **all** implications. I have strong doubts.

Comment: @kdopen: There hardly is any sense in using `volatile` function parameters.

Comment: @kdopen: why would adding the volatile to the function prototype be appropriate? I'd argue the converse — the value passed will normally be copied onto the stack, and that is not volatile within the meaning of the term (or, if it is, there are bigger problems — like volatile return addresses also being stored on the stack). When you call the function, the value from the volatile variable will be read (as required by volatile — but it'd probably happen even without the volatile qualifier, unless the value would otherwise be stored in a register, or …) and the value passed to the function.

Comment: Using `volatile` in conjunction with pointer parameters can make sense; if the data the pointer points at can change behind the scenes, that's crucial for the compiler to know.  But simple value parameters marked volatile; that's tantamount to an abuse of `volatile`.

Comment: @kdopen This seems to be the opposite of that question, which is about having the `volatile` qualifier on the function argument/return type, not the variable being passed to the function.

Comment: What is the actual warning message you're getting?

Comment: Olaf, you are totally right about my mistake using "modifier" instead of  "qualifier". English is not my native language. About my knowledge of "volatile qualifier" I think I understand how it works, but as I said, I have doubts about it's behavior when using casts. I will be glad to learn from you if you want to teach me. Thanks

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It depends on what he wants to do with it inside `my_fiunction` - see my answer

Comment: @cventu English is not Olaf's native language either, though it is hard to tell.

Comment: @kdopen: I'm not convinced by the non-pointer part of your answer.  It makes no sense to me to use `volatile` without a pointer in a function's argument list.  I'm not going to continue the argument: I think we're starting from different premises and therefore aren't going to agree.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I did put a pointer in the new function spec. Which bit needs clarification? It's one of those "hard to explain what you take for granted' things

Comment: @kdopen: The whole paragraph _When you pass a volatile into a function as a value-parameter, you only get one read of the variable. This may then be used multiple times within the function (effectively losing the volatile nature)._ worries me.  There's an implication that you think C does (or should) provide a way of reading the variable used to pass a parameter to a function more than once when it is not passed via a pointer.  You asked; I gave.  I don't plan to discuss much further, if at all.

Comment: Got you - should be clearer now. thanks

Comment: @WeatherVane: I take that as a compliment (feel free to correct me:-). You are right. More important is since I joined here, I have the standard under my pillow and bookmarked. I'd recommend anyone programming C to do the same.

Comment: @Olaf it was, not diminished by the fact that I had not noticed what OP confessed. As for the standard, I no longer code for other people, but I have worked for well known names who are not shy of driving a coach and horses (or 6 inch nail) thorough whatever stands in their way.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I very well know what you mean. I have the same problem with increasing frequency (at least that's what it appears to me) to keep customers from such and other nonsense.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: By the way, and trying to complete the comment by Olaf, what is the exact warning you receive?  You mention it several times, but is better to show it (only once) completely, than to explain that you are able to hide it (warnings are there not to hide the cause, but to assist you in correct programming)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really depends on what `my_function` **does** with its argument.

Remember that `volatile` prevents certain optimizations - predominantly it forces the variable to be re-read every time it is referenced. Thus this code

```
volatile int a;
int b;
// ...
b = a + 1;
b = a + 2;
```

will read `a` for each statement and, as `a` may have changed values between them, give the correct result.

When you pass a `volatile` into a function as a parameter, you only get one `read` of the variable. This may then be used multiple times within the function (effectively losing the `volatile` nature).

Remember that C is pass-by-value. When you invoke the function as

```
my_function((int)b); // b is declared volatile
```

The compiler generates code to read `b` once in the calling code, and push the value it read onto the stack (usually), then invoke `my_function`. This copy is then referenced within `my_function` as `example`, and no matter how often you reference `example` you will always get the same value (even if the original `b` variable has since changed many times).

That might be exactly what you want - take a snapshot of the variable and do several computations on its value.

If it's not what you want, you need to consider passing in a **pointer** with the appropriate `volatile` qualifications.

```
char my_function( volatile int *example);
```

And call it thus:

```
my_function(&a);
my_function(&b);
```

Then reference `*example` inside `my_function`.

Comment: That is pretty nonsense. If the variable you **pass** into a function shall be `volatile`, you have to _declare the variable `volatile`, not cast the _expression_ you use for the parameter to `volatile`. I can'tr even see how that would change anything in the code, because you cast the expression to `volatile`, then assign the result to a non-`volatile` parameter.

Comment: Your pointer example, though valid usage, is completely different, as it does not qualify the parameter `volatile`, but the _object it points to_. A `volatile` pointer would be `int * volatile p` and of as little use as the `int i` parameter.

Comment: And it is indeed the "value it points to" which is volatile, not the pointer.

Comment: _values_ cannot be `volatile` (that is the problem with the cast), but objects can. Btw., there is **one** application to use `volatile` aguments, but this is not used here and I strongly discourage to use it.

Comment: I'm lost, where am I casting anything?

Comment: I refered to OPs original version. But your code also includes a very questionable cast. Note that there is not even a requirement for the compiler to do a read of the value in `b` unless the object is `volatile`.

Comment: @Olaf The only cast in my answer (`my_function((int)b)`) is reproducing the one in the OP's post, for explanatory reasons. The only value it has is to suppress a warning his compiler may be generating. Not everyone uses gcc

Comment: "The compiler generates code to read b once in the calling code, and push the value it read onto the stack (usually)" - There is no requirement to actually read `b`, nor is there any requirement for a stack in C. Even if you refer to typical implementations ("usually"), this is typically wrong for such functions, are they _typically_ pass the first (and often subsequent) arguments in registers (accumulator, GP registers, etc).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121096/discussion-between-kdopen-and-olaf).

Answer (score 1):

The cast doesn't actually do anything. In the call my_function (b); the code reads the volatile int b. That's where the "volatile" matters, during the read. The result of the read is already an int and not a volatile int. There are no volatile int values. Even if there were volatile int values, passing it to my_function would convert it to plain int, just as the cast does.

It *may* be that the compiler assumes that passing a volatile int variable to a function is something dangerous worth a warning, and by adding a cast to int you indicate that you know what you are doing.

Comment: That warning would definitively wrong. The volatile qualifier is not part of the value, but only lvalues (like all qualifiers, see 6.7.3p4). Such a compiler is suspectible to have other faults. I'm not sure I'd be able to trust that thing to generate proper code.